# Emacs, How can I display only current task and hide others in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Org-mode.
I have a big tasks tree and I want to select only 1 in buffer (write notes just for it) and hide others while editing.
How can I do this?

```
task-1
  subtask-1.1
  subtask-1.2
task-2
  subtask2.1
...
...
```

For example I want to display for me only:

```
subtask-1.2
(notes for this subtask)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `narrow-to-defun` or `org-narrow-to-subtree` command with point in task. (`widen` to move back to whole buffer content).

Default shortcuts:

```
C-x n s      # org-narrow-to-subtree (bound in org-mode)
C-x n d      # narrow-to-defun
C-x n w      # widen
```

[Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html)

Answer (score 3):

You also have `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer`, or `C-c C-x b`, which will create a new buffer with only this subtree, and reflect any change in one buffer into the other.